# applying a function to faker

Tags: python, factory, factory-boy

So I have an object like this:

```
class ContactPhoneFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = ContactPhoneNumber

    number = Faker().phone_number()
    type = factory.Faker('random_element', elements=range(5))
```

I want to apply a function 'formatted_number' to 'number'

if I apply:

```
number = formatted_number(Faker().phone_number())
```

it won't apply the function to the output of Faker, it'll just take the Faker object as input.  Lazy attribute causes the same problem.  How can I apply the formatting function to the faker object?

Answer (score 1):

I've hit a very similar issue myself (also on the PhoneNumber factory): I just wanted to restrict the numbers faker generates to only mobile numbers.

I just implemented my own faker provider. This has the added benefit of not being tied to factory-boy API changes (faker is still pretty new to factory-boy).

I think it goes something like this:

```
from faker.providers.phone_number import Provider as PhoneProvider

class MyPhoneProvider(PhoneProvider):
    @classmethod
    def formatted_phone_number(cls):
        return formatted_number(cls.phone_number())

factory.Faker.add_provider(MyPhoneProvider)

number = factory.Faker('formatted_phone_number')
```